# Syntax error: unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyp = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");    
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyp.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function(req, res){

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

    const finame = req.body.fname;
    const laname = req.body.lname;
    const mail = req.body.email;

    const data = {
        members: [
            {
                email_address: mail,
                status: "subscribed",
                merge_fields: {
                    FNAME: finame,
                    LNAME: laname
                },
            },
        ],
    };

    const jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);

    const url = "https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/d07ffaae94";

    const options = {
        method:"post",
        auth:"XXXXXXXXXXX"
    };

    const request = https.request(url, options, function(response){

        if(response.statusCode === 200){

            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
        }
        else{
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
        }

        response.on("data", function(data){
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });

    request.write(jsondata);
    request.end();
});


app.post("/failure", function(req, res){
    
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){

    console.log("Server is running on port 3000.");
});
```

I have tried adding commas and so many other things but I don't understand how this error will get fixed. Please give any help or suggestions. I wrote this code with the help of Angela Yu's course and did all the steps exactly as she told and I still don't understand why it is giving me an error.

Comment: it is giving syntax error at the line : console.log(JSON.parse(data));

Comment: Can you just comment it out and try it? just for the test comment it like // console.log(JSON.parse(data));.

Comment: Ensure that you are using the correct endpoint for the Mailchimp API. Also API key in the `auth` field

Comment: `response.on("data", ...)` typically isn't delivering all of the response in one clal to the callback, thus you are trying to parse an incomplete chunk of JSON

Comment: @Adil i commented it out and wow it worked like magic! but can you explain the logic because of which it works like this? i have written this code with the help of angela yu's course and all the steps ive made are following hers but she didnt get any error neither did she comment out this line so why is it different for me?

Comment: @derpirscher um im sorry but what do you mean by one clal? what is a clal?

Comment: @AmnaIftikhar data is not there completely and you are trying to parse it that's why it was giving an error. derpirscher said the same thing above, he meant, response in one call to the callback.

Comment: I'd suggest using `fetch()` instead of `https.request()`. At least then you'd be dealing with a complete response

Comment: Typo, "one call" ie the `on("data" ...)` callback is called multiple times until all data is received. See the linked duplicate

Comment: It's not "working like magic". You just disabled the faulty statement so that it isn't doing anything at all. But that's not gonna help you, if you need that data you are trying to receive from the response.